# CSS height 100% in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a difficult layout in my website and I have a problem now with IE7. How can I in this example set the inner wrapper to fill the height of the outer wrapper?

http://jsfiddle.net/fMPNw/2/

Comment: Dont be a troll... In the history we can see that you have taken the "Thanks" out with your another fake account -_-

Comment: @Shredder: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @Dbugger: Shredder was asking Nightfirecat (a member with over 2,000 reputation) why he removed the *Thanks!* part. You should **not** say thanks as part of your question.

Comment: @Shredder Sorry, I thought it was you who erased the "thanks". Now I get what happened. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly define the height of .wrapper, in that situation. That being said, if your top: and bottom: attributes are going to make the height dynamic, your only solution is resetting the height with JavaScript, binding the height to update on window resize, etc.

Comment: I feared so. Too bad :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get .wrapper2 to layout correctly by making it absolutely positioned. Using the following 2 lines of CSS, width to correct the width issue caused by absolute positioning.

```
position:absolute;
width:100%;
```

End result being:

```
.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 310px;
    bottom: 130px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
}
.wrapper2{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem when people need inner elements not to be absolutely positioned. For example, when the inner element needs to be floated beside a second element. Of course, if your inner element can be absolute, you might as well use `top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right 0px;`