# How to fill 100% of an absolutely positioned div? (IE7+)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS height 100% in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160417/css-height-100-in-ie7)

I'd like to have a centered block on a webpage that's filled to 100% by a child div.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#parent {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: blue;
   top: 2em;
   left: 4em;
   bottom: 3em;
   right: 2em;  
}

#child {
   position: relative;
   background-color: red;
   height: 100%;   
}
```

And here is a JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XMS2G/1/

The problem is that in Internet Explorer 7, the browser does not cause the child div to expand to the entire parent div. How would I accomplish this without using Javascript?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question, but what about min-height and min-width for your child css styles?

Comment: Is IE7 really a platform, which hs to be supported?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach, unfortunately yes :(

Comment: Do you have a valid Doc-Type definition? The IE will use completely different rendering if a doctype is present

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach I'm currently using the HTML5 doctype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using `position:absolute` for child as well. And then just use `top:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; left:0px;`

I think it will work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give the child `position: absolute` and set `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` to `0`.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/L6X9v/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely have to set a hard-coded width for the parent DIV to get IE7 to behave nicely. the centering can be done with the "margin-left: auto;" "margin-right: auto;" css.